# Clicking on React-slick item doesn't redirect to the correct link

Tags: reactjs, next.js, carousel, chakra-ui, react-slick

I have a carousel component made using react-slick, the problem is that when i click on an image it should redirect me to the specified link, but that is not the case as it keeps sending me to the last link.

I've logged the cards which the unique links before setting them in the href, and they all turned out as expected unique. I tried using next router with an onClick listener so that it redirects me to the correct link but it too didn't work, and so I expect it has something to do with react-slick.

**First the data I am passing:**

```
{
      // Cyperpunk
      link: "/games/27",
      image:
        "/cyberPunk.png",
    },
    {
      // NBA
      link: "/games/41",
      image:
        "/NBA.jpeg",
    },
    {
      // Call of duty
      link: "/games/7",
      image: "/callOfDuty.png",
    }
```

**Carousel.jsx**

```
import { Box, IconButton, useBreakpointValue } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import Slider from "react-slick";
import Link from "next/link";
import { useState } from "react";
import { ChevronLeftIcon, ChevronRightIcon } from "@chakra-ui/icons";
const settings = {
  dots: true,
  arrows: false,
  fade: true,
  infinite: true,
  autoplay: true,
  speed: 500,
  autoplaySpeed: 5000,
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 3,
};

export default function Carousel({ cards }) {
  const [slider, setSlider] = useState(null);

  const top = useBreakpointValue({ base: "90%", md: "50%" });
  const side = useBreakpointValue({ base: "30%", md: "40px" });

  return (
    <Box position={"relative"} width={"full"} overflow={"hidden"}>
      {/* CSS files for react-slick */}
      <link
        rel="stylesheet"
        type="text/css"
        charSet="UTF-8"
        href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.css"
      />
      <link
        rel="stylesheet"
        type="text/css"
        href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick-theme.min.css"
      />
      {/* Left Icon */}
      <IconButton
        top={top}
        zIndex={2}
        left={side}
        variant="ghost"
        bgColor={"white"}
        position="absolute"
        as={ChevronLeftIcon}
        aria-label="left-arrow"
        transform={"translate(0%, -50%)"}
        onClick={() => slider?.slickPrev()}
      />
      {/* Right Icon */}
      <IconButton
        top={top}
        zIndex={2}
        right={side}
        variant="ghost"
        bgColor={"white"}
        position="absolute"
        as={ChevronRightIcon}
        aria-label="right-arrow"
        transform={"translate(0%, -50%)"}
        onClick={() => slider?.slickNext()}
      />
      {/* Slider */}
      <Slider {...settings} ref={(slider) => setSlider(slider)}>
        {cards?.map((card, index) => {
          console.log("%%%%%%%%%%%");
          console.log(cards);
          console.log("%%%%%%%%%%%");
          return (
            <Link key={index} href={card.link}>
              <Box
                height={["65vw", "60vw", "50vw"]}
                position="relative"
                objectFit={"cover"}
                backgroundPosition="center"
                backgroundRepeat="no-repeat"
                backgroundSize="cover"
                backgroundImage={`url(${card.image})`}></Box>
            </Link>
          );
        })}
      </Slider>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

**Where I think the problem is:**

**Here:**

```
// Carousel.jsx
const settings = {
  dots: true,
  arrows: false,
  fade: true,
  infinite: true,
  autoplay: true,
  speed: 500,
  autoplaySpeed: 5000,
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 3,
};
```

**OR**

```
<Slider {...settings} ref={(slider) => setSlider(slider)}>
        {cards?.map((card, index) => {
          console.log("%%%%%%%%%%%");
          console.log(cards);
          console.log("%%%%%%%%%%%");
          return (
            <Link key={index} href={card.link}>
              <Box
                height={["65vw", "60vw", "50vw"]}
                position="relative"
                objectFit={"cover"}
                backgroundPosition="center"
                backgroundRepeat="no-repeat"
                backgroundSize="cover"
                backgroundImage={`url(${card.image})`}></Box>
            </Link>
          );
        })}
      </Slider>
```